# Rails access 2 records at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to print 2 records on one page. I have around 513 database records. I know in ruby you can use something like `range.step(2).each do ...` , is it possible to do it with rails and an active record collection?

like:

```
Users.step(2).each_with_index ...

  do something with User(i)
  do something with User (i+1)
  blah blah
...
.

end
```

Comment: undefined method `step' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` relations can be treated as arrays, so they also have [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method implemented:

```
User.all.each_slice(2) do |user1, user2|
  # code goes here
end
```

Answer (score 1):

what about `User.find_each(batch_size: 2)` ?

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 2`

`#<User:0x007fa92ec82f60>`

`#<User:0x007fa92ec82b78>`

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 2`

`#<User:0x007fa92ec82f60>`

`#<User:0x007fa92ec82b78>`

.........

Rails [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each)
He would get all the records in 2 pieces.

Comment: thanks mate, I thought of batch, but it is usually used for 1000+ records so I don't know if it is the best practise

Comment: 500 entries norms but if it records 10000 server lies.